# VueJS view changes doesnt reflect in laravel Xampp

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, webpack

This is my first time with VueJS inside a Laravel PHP framework. Got some new project. Made some changes like adding new elements, changing titles etc. No of my changes are reflected when I do **php artisan serve**. From the Chromes network window, tracked down all the us part dumped inside a single app.js file.

So deleted all content of the app.js file and ran **npm run development**, to confirm, and as expected **js/app.js** is auto populated with my latest changes. I did put some rubbish text in there to check and found it on the minified version.

But for some reason, could be my fate, the localhost still didn't have my cosmetic change or the rubbish text.
Cleared browser cache, did npm install, Vuejs cache clearing etc. Nothing worked. I am almost in a state of giving up. Any help in moving forward is highly appreciated. I  believe it could be a very basic command I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

`npm run dev` didn't change your executed, after your change the code first you should terminate the console and run `npm run dev` again. or just

```
npm run watch
```

your code automaticly change without `npm run dev`